# How to optimize this query for import/export data, from 2 table to 1 table with morethan 200k record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

there is a third table will be filled with data from first table and second table.

the third table should be accommodate as many records from 
(first table)*(second table)

and before importing data, the data should be checked beforehand,
because if the records already existed, the import process will be passed to the next record.

and this is my query

```
$queryS = "SELECT id FROM tabel where x=$x ";
$resultS = $Databaseku->prepare($queryS);
$resultS->execute();    
while($dataS = $resultS->fetch())
{
    $id         = $dataS["id"]; 

    $queryK = "SELECT id FROM tabel2 where y=$y ";
    $resultK = $Databaseku->prepare($queryK);
    $resultK->execute();
    $j=1;
    while($dataK = $resultK->fetch())
    {
        $idK        = $dataK["id"];  

        $cekdata    = "select a,b,c from tabel3 where a=$id AND b=$idK"; 
        $ada        = mysql_query($cekdata) or die(mysql_error()); 

        if(mysql_num_rows($ada)>0) 
        {    
            //record-$j already. do nothing 
        } 

        else 
        {       
            $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tabel3 (a, b, c) VALUES (:a, :b, :c)";
            $result = $Databaseku->prepare($query); 
            $data  = array(                                     
                        ':a'    => $id,
                        ':b'    => $idK,
                        ':c'    => $c
                        );                  
            $result->execute($data);

            }
            $result=null;

        $j++;   
        }   
    $resultK=null;
    }

$resultS=null;

echo "Succed";
```

Comment: Your premise works, but I question the point of such a query, especially if it's being run regularly.  It seems like it'd be much more efficient to just run a single join query on demand to get data.  If properly indexed, 200k records shouldn't take more than a second or two to query.

Comment: yeah you right, but after update with left join betwen table 1 and table 2
query still slow.. is it possible because i use innoDB, than MyISAM ?

Comment: Why don't you post your table data along with indices.  That's the key to performance here -- indexing.  200k records is nothing....it's possible to search millions of records in very reasonable amounts of time.

Comment: with this query

INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 (a, b, c)
SELECT  table1.a, table2.b, table1.c  FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN program ON table1.years = table2.years WHERE table2.years = '$years' 

its work less than 8second, 130k record done, 

but

when i need verification 
if the records already existed, 
the import process will be passed to the next record

query still need 1 hours to do that

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not execute this queries on every iteration if it is possible `SELECT id FROM tabel2 where x=$x`, `select a,b,c from tabel3 where d=$d`. Do it once before loop.
2. Insert data by groups, do not execute insert for each record. For example, insert groups with 1000 records:

   ```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO tabel3 (a, b, c) VALUES 
   (:a1, :b1, :c1), 
   (:a2, :b2, :c2), 
   ...
   (:a1000, :b1000, :c1000);
   ```

Comment: 1. well i need that because i will use $id for a and $idK for b  
2. i dont know how.. because tabel 2 and tabel 3 is dynamic

Comment: 2. Fill `$query` in cycle. Before while: `$query = "INSERT (...) VALUES "`. Inside while: `$query .= "(...)"`. After while run `execute()`.